# Storing values in separate CPU cache banks

Tags: caching, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

As part of a class project I am looking at ways to improve the performance of a path finding algorithm in a CPU architecture. The algorithm is implemented in C++. The basic operation is to read x,y coordinates and perform some operations on them.

The idea I have right now is to store x and y coordinates separately in two cache banks(set associative). Two coordinates entered for a location should be stored in different banks such that it should be able to read them both in parallel and do separate operations on x and y coordinates and store the combined result. By using vector operations this process can be further sped up to read up to 4 x coordinates and 4 y coordinates at the same time.

For example, for computing euclidean distance from the goal node, at each location the x and y coordinates has to be read and subtracted from goal coordinates to find out the distance.

I wish to know if there is an effective way(cache placement policy) to keep x and y coordinates in different cache lines/blocks for taking advantage of parallelism. Is there any operation/encoding of coordinates I can use to implement it?

P.S: I am not looking for software optimizations but for a modified cache design(theoretical) to speed up the algorithm.

Ref: This [blog post](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) mentions that "L1 cache can process two accesses in parallel if they access cache lines from different banks, and serially if they belong to the same bank."

Answer (score 0):

A coordinate held in a structure like this:

```
struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} coordinate;
```

will fit into a single cache line. In fact, on typical MIPS processors with a 32 byte cache line, 8 instances of `coordinate` will fit into a cache line. The CPU will read the entire line at once from a single bank or *way* in the data cache, and all 32 bytes, or all 4 coordinates will thenceforth be available in a 32 byte *fill/store buffer* (FSB) at zero delay to the pipeline. MIPS processors with caches typically have more than one FSB.

MIPS processors with banked or *set-associative* caches typically use a [LRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) algorithm to select which bank/way new data is placed into on a cache miss. It is not generally possible to ensure that data from a certain location always gets placed into a particular *way* in the cache.

All this is to say that your scheme of storing x and y coordinates in separate cache banks will not improve performance over a naive scheme because of the positive effects of the FSBs on the naive scheme and because of the unpredictable effects of the *way* selection algorithm for the cache.

Comment: A _bank_ is not the same as a _way_.